# More than one Agent in a single module

Tags: elixir

Is it okay to have more than one Agent in a module? For instance, I am creating a game and I need a wrapper for the state of the game as well as a wrapper for the state of the users. An example:

```
defmodule TicTacToe do

  def start_game do
    Agent.start_link(..., name: Moves)
    Agent.start_link(..., name: Users)
  end

end
```

The examples in the docs show a single `Agent.start_link` which makes me think there shouldn't be more than one Agent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is absolutely legit to have as many `Agent`s as you want (they are still erlang’s `gen_server`s under the hood,) there is no need in two agents in this particular case.

The rule of thumb is “do not produce superfluous servers.“

One map with keys `:moves` and `:users` would perfectly suffice here:

```
@doc """
Starts a new single agent for both moves and users.
"""
def start_link do
  Agent.start_link(fn -> %{moves: %{}, users: %{}} end)
end

@doc """
Gets a move by `key`.
"""
def get_move(key) do
  Agent.get(&get_in(&1, [:moves, key]))
end
```

Here we use the deep map digging with [`Kernel.get_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#get_in/2). That is preferrable way because as soon as you are writing the robust application, you should take care about data consistence over crashes, and it’s easier to just take care about one `Agent`, rather than keep many of them consistent.